# Discord Error 403 error code: 50001 Missing Access

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

when i run `python3.9 -m ctbot`

i got this error, and the slash command will not be updated. after i kicked my bot and reinvited my bot to my server, the slash command didnt appear.

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at /home/tershi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py:416> exception=Forbidden('403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tershi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 440, in sync_all_commands
    existing_cmds = await self.req.get_all_commands(guild_id=scope)
  File "/home/tershi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

[image: My bot permission]

And i followed the solutions, turned it on, then it didnt work for me.
[image]

Github Repo: https://github.com/Cutespirit-Team/CutespiritDiscordBot

How can I fix the error? thx

Comment: Did u activate it programatically?

Comment: yes. run in ```python3.9 -m ctbot```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

On top of enabling in the portal,you need to activate it programmatically.

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Comment: github repo: https://github.com/Cutespirit-Team/CutespiritDiscordBot how can i fix the error thx